# Sending request body with DefaultHttpClient

Tags: java, http, oauth-2.0, http-post

I am trying to get an authentication token from an auth endpoint in Java using the DefaultHTTPClient

Here is the curl command that I am trying to reproduce in Java

```
curl -u "user:pass" -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST -d "grant_type=basic" http://auth.myCompany.com/v1/oauth2/token
```

Here is the Java snippet

```
DefaultHttpClient dhttpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

String username = "user";
String password = "pass";
String uri = "http://auth.myCompany.com/v1/oauth2/token";

try
{
    dhttpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));
    HttpPost dhttppost = new HttpPost(uri);
    dhttppost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    /** How to add request Body here **/
    dhttppost.ADD_REQUEST_BODY(grant_type = basic??)

    System.out.println("executing request " + dhttppost.getRequestLine());
    HttpResponse dresponse = dhttpclient.execute(dhttppost);

    System.out.println("StatusLine" + dresponse.getStatusLine()    );
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
    dhttpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
}
```

Adding the following gives a 400- Bad Request

```
dhttppost.setEntity(new StringEntity("grant_type=basic"));
```

Also this gives a bad request error

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "basic"));
dhttppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
```

Some logging gave me the following

```
DEBUG [2016-06-28 19:08:52,059] org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestTargetAuthentication: Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
```

Is this expected?